# How to use dynamic programming for cutting a rod of length n so that it will be the most profitable

Tags: c++, optimization, dynamic-programming

The rod cutting problem is as follows:

Given a rod of length n inches and a table of prices pi for i = 1, 2, ..., n, determine the maximum revenue Rn obtainable by cutting up the rod and selling the pieces. Note that if the price Pn for a rod of length n is large enough, an optimal solution may require no cutting at all.

```
 Consider the following example:
 length i   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 price pi   1 5 8 9 10 17 17 20 24 30
```

Consider the case when n = 4. Cutting a 4-inch rod into two 2-inch pieces produces revenue p2 + p2 = 5 + 5 = 10, which is optimal.Write a program for solving the problem from above such that the time complexity is not higher than Θ(n^2). Your solution has to determine the optimal revenue without the listing of the cuts.

I have developed the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

using namespace std;

int max(int a, int b) {return (a > b)? a : b;} 

int cutRod(int price[], int n){
    int r[n+1];
    r[0] = 0; //solution array
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        int q = INT_MIN;
        for( int j = 1; j <= i; j++)  {
            q = max(q, price[j-1] + r[i-j]);
            r[i] = q;        
        }
    }
    return r[n];
}

int main() {
    int price[] = {1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 17, 20, 24, 30};

    cout << cutRod(price, 1) << endl; 
    cout << cutRod(price, 2) << endl; 
    cout << cutRod(price, 3) << endl; 
    cout << cutRod(price, 4) << endl; 
    cout << cutRod(price, 5) << endl; 
    cout << cutRod(price, 6) << endl;
    cout << cutRod(price, 7) << endl;
    cout << cutRod(price, 8) << endl; 
    cout << cutRod(price, 9) << endl; 
    cout << cutRod(price, 10) << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

I get no errors during compilation, but when I run it the outcome is the following:

```
 1
 5
 8
 10
 13
 17
 20
 24
 30
 32766
```

which means that for n = 9 and for n = 10, we have that the max revenue is 30 and 32766 respectively. This is wrong as the max revenue for n = 9 is 24 and n = 10 is 30. I have tried re structuring the for loop but I am not able to correct this. My question here is what part of the code is incorrect for the revenues for n => 8 to be incorrect. Any help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: You access the arrays out of bounds. That causes undefined behavior. `j` goes up to `10` and `price[9]` is undefined behavior. You forgot one value in `price`: `int price[] = {1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 17, 20, 24, 30};` => `int price[] = {1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 17, 17, 20, 24, 30};`

Answer (score 0):

You have 9 elements in your array... (Off-by-one)

Also, as a side note, you should use the C++ algorithms instead of your own `max` function (`std::max` is in `<algorithm>`), and in C++ code don't use `.h` system headers (use their C++ equivalent, so here they would be `cstdio`, which you don't actually use here, and `climits`).

As a second side note, you should respect constness (so put a `const` in front of the `int price[]` in the argument list, it may show some bugs).

As a third side note, instead of `INT_MIN` you can just use 0.

As a fourth side note, maybe use `std::array`? (Though that is purely optional and a matter of preferences! You may need an array, in which case, nevermind.)

As a final side note, since array are 0-indexed in C/C++, you should make your loops start at 0 and not 1 (though once again that is a matter of preferences).

(PS: I just noticed, in the example you provided above you have a `17` twice in the prices, for 6 and 7 units of length.)